# Spark connection pooling - Is this the right approach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, connection-pooling, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark job in Structured Streaming that consumes data from Kafka and saves it to InfluxDB. I have implemented the connection pooling mechanism as follows:

```
object InfluxConnectionPool {
      val queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue[InfluxDB]()

      def initialize(database: String): Unit = {
        while (!isConnectionPoolFull) {
          queue.put(createNewConnection(database))
        }
      }

      private def isConnectionPoolFull: Boolean = {
        val MAX_POOL_SIZE = 1000
        if (queue.size < MAX_POOL_SIZE)
          false
        else
          true
      }

      def getConnectionFromPool: InfluxDB = {
        if (queue.size > 0) {
          val connection = queue.take()
          connection
        } else {
          System.err.println("InfluxDB connection limit reached. ");
          null
        }

      }

      private def createNewConnection(database: String) = {
        val influxDBUrl = "..."
        val influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(...)
        influxDB.enableBatch(10, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        influxDB.setDatabase(database)
        influxDB.setRetentionPolicy(database + "_rp")
        influxDB
      }

      def returnConnectionToPool(connection: InfluxDB): Unit = {
        queue.put(connection)
      }
    }
```

In my spark job, I do the following

```
def run(): Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("ETL JOB")
  .master("local[4]")
  .getOrCreate()


 ...

 // This is where I create connection pool
InfluxConnectionPool.initialize("dbname")

val sdvWriter = new ForeachWriter[record] {
  var influxDB:InfluxDB = _

  def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    influxDB = InfluxConnectionPool.getConnectionFromPool
    true
  }
  def process(record: record) = {
    // this is where I use the connection object and save the data
    MyService.saveData(influxDB, record.topic, record.value)
    InfluxConnectionPool.returnConnectionToPool(influxDB)
  }
  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
  }
}

import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//Read data from kafka
val kafkaStreamingDF = spark
  .readStream
  ....

val sdvQuery = kafkaStreamingDF
  .writeStream
  .foreach(sdvWriter)
  .start()
  }
```

But, when I run the job, I get the following exception

```
18/05/07 00:00:43 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 6af3c096-7158-40d9-9523-13a6bffccbb8, runId = 3b620d11-9b93-462b-9929-ccd2b1ae9027] terminated with error
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 8, 192.168.222.5, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:332)
        at com.abc.telemetry.app.influxdb.InfluxConnectionPool$.returnConnectionToPool(InfluxConnectionPool.scala:47)
        at com.abc.telemetry.app.ETLappSave$$anon$1.process(ETLappSave.scala:55)
        at com.abc.telemetry.app.ETLappSave$$anon$1.process(ETLappSave.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:49)
```

The NPE is when the connection is returned to the connection pool in queue.put(connection). What am I missing here? Any help appreciated.

P.S: In the regular DStreams approach, I did it with foreachPartition method. Not sure how to do connection reuse/pooling with structured streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the forEachWriter for redis similarly, where the pool is being referenced in the process only. Your request would look something like below

````
def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    true
  }

  def process(record: record) = {
    influxDB = InfluxConnectionPool.getConnectionFromPool
    // this is where I use the connection object and save the data
    MyService.saveData(influxDB, record.topic, record.value)
    InfluxConnectionPool.returnConnectionToPool(influxDB)
  }```
````

Answer (score -1):

```
datasetOfString.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[String] {
      def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
        // open connection
      }
      def process(record: String) = {
        // write string to connection
      }
      def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
        // close the connection
      }
    })
```

From the docs of ForeachWriter,

```
Each task will get a fresh serialized-deserialized copy of the provided object
```

So whatever you initialize outside the ForeachWriter will run only at the driver.

You need to initialize the connection pool and open the connection in the open method.

Comment: If you `initialize the connection pool and open the connection in the open method.`, a new connection pool will be created for every task, probably not a good idea to init a connection pool in open method