# Spark structured streaming foreachpartition / connection pooling issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading data from Kafka using structured streaming and I need to save 
the data to InfluxDB. In the regular Dstreams based approach I did this as 
follows:

```scala
val messages:DStream[(String, String)] =  kafkaStream.map(record => 
(record.topic, record.value)) 
messages.foreachRDD { rdd => 
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords => 
    val influxService = new InfluxService() 
    val connection = influxService.createInfluxDBConnectionWithParams( 
        host, 
        port, 
        username, 
        password, 
        database 
        ) 
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => { 
      ABCService.handleData(connection, record._1, record._2) 
    } 
    ) 
  } 
} 
ssc.start() 
logger.info("Started Spark-Kafka streaming session") 
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**Note**:

I create connection object inside `foreachpartition`. How do I do this 
in Structured Streaming?

I tried connection pooling approach (where I 
create a pool of connections on the master node and pass it to worker nodes 
)  here 
[Spark connection pooling - Is this the right approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205650/spark-connection-pooling-is-this-the-right-approach)
and the workers could not get the connection pool object. Anything obvious 
that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Structured Streaming has completely different design, and old `RDD` based patterns are not really applicable there.

Instead you should implement your own [`ForeachWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter)  . It requires three methods:

- `open`

  > `abstract def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean`
  >   Called when starting to process one partition of new data in the executor.

  This is where you initialize connection objects. In general it shouldn't depend on objects passed with closure (the mistake you've made in you second question).

  If you want to limit the number of connections you can use singletons objects, as long as, all components are thread safe.
- `process`

  > ```
  > abstract def process(value: T): Unit
  > ```
  >
  > Called to process the data in the executor side.

  This is equivalent of `foreach`.
- `close`

  > `abstract def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit`
  >
  > Called when stopping to process one partition of new data in the executor side.

  This is where you can close connections and dipsose other temporary  objects.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I did try that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205650/spark-connection-pooling-is-this-the-right-approach) and it did not work.

Comment: The open gets called several times during the course of data processing  even though my Kafka topic has 3 partitions. So if I create connection object in open() block, it gets called several times leading to out of memory exception

Comment: The same thing would have to happen with `foreachPartition`. Connection objects are not designed to be serialized and send over the wire. You can try use singleton object to store pool, as long as all components are thread safe

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Do you mind looking at this approach ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205650/spark-connection-pooling-is-this-the-right-approach

Comment: One problem in your other question is that you `initalize` on the driver, not on the workers. But I don't see why initializing connection in `open` and closing inc `close` would cause any memory issues.

Comment: Hi /u/user9613318 I tried the same logic of creating connections in open method and it worked. Not sure why it was not working earlier.

Comment: It would be quite helpful to have a more complete example: the above is too far from a working snippet.